# VueJs Scroll bar desappering after switching to mobile view

Tags: vue.js, mobile, scrollbar

I started an internship, and they gave me an existing app to improve in VueJs. However I still a beginner in web dev. 
Here's my problem: there is a form that is divided into many rows, each one contains a lot of inputs, so I added a scroll bar as the user can fill them all, but once I switch to mobile mode, 
it appears in the first row, but when I go to others it disappears. After re-switching to the PC mode, and going to another row, it reappears.

```js
<template>
  <v-tab-item>
    <v-container
      id="scroll-target"
      style="max-height: 400px"
      class="overflow-y-auto"
    >
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card  v-if="##############">
        <v-card-text>
            <inputs v-bind="$props" />
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
      <v-row  v-for="########":key="#####">
      <v-col>
        <inputSectionCard :######" />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row v-if="#####">
          <v-col>
            <localisationCard />
          </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row v-if="####">
          <v-col>
            <attachments />
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-card>
      <scrollbar />
   </v-container>
  </v-tab-item>
</template>
 
 component scrollBar:
 <template>
  <v-row
    v-scroll:#scroll-target="onScroll"
    align="center"
    justify="center"
    style="height: 100%"
  >
  </v-row>
  </template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    offsetTop: 0
  }),

  methods: {
    onScroll(e) {
      this.offsetTop = e.target.scrollTop
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: How did you add the scrollbar? You should provide some code example so people can imagine what could be wrong.

Comment: I added some code, sorry for the #### I used it to hide the work they did before me.